# How to render html in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My HTML is: (I'm using knockout)

```
<p class="req" data-bind="text:loginError"></p> // show error text here
```

Js code is:

```
if(serverError == "Incorrect Password"){
    var link = $('<a/>').text("Forget password").attr('href', '/Account/ForgetPassword');
    loginError = "Incorrect password." + link[0].outerHTML + " ?";
}
```

But output is:

```
Incorrect password.<a href="/Account/ForgetPassword">Forget password</a> ?
```

How can I get output as link?

Comment: I found a bit confuse to understand the problem. could you add more details?

Comment: I have updated question. please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "html" ko binding to display HTML elements:

```
<p class="req" data-bind="text:loginError, html: link"></p>
```

Then, in your code define both bindings elements:

```
if(serverError == "Incorrect Password"){
    loginError = "Incorrect password.";
    link = '<a href="/Account/ForgetPassword">Forgot password?</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting a string loginError. You have to insert it as Control. Your placeholder is the

```
$('p.req').append(logingError):
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean

### $('.req').html(link) ?

You are returning link[0].outerHTML that contains the html in text format. If you use your var "link" it contains the jQuery object, so you use it into your p element called '.req'.
Here is the example:
jsfiddle.net/u8nqmmrk

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't understand your answer. Please provide more details

Comment: $('.req') - get your 'p' element where you will show your error
link is your element 'a' (link), and html() write the dom

Comment: Edit your answer to make it clearer, don't just hide info in comments